# Does mispronunciation after ruku invalidate salat?

Tags: salat, fiqh, sharia, muslim-practices

I was praying fajr and I accidentally said "rabbana wa lakan hamd" instead of "rabbana wa lakal hamd". Is my prayer valid? I heard that mispronunciation in fatiha can invalidate salah, but what is the ruling here? I am not a native arabic speaker and I didn’t really correct my mistake, although I did notice it after I said it.

Comment: Please clarify using the edit link at the bottom of your post: Are you a native Arabic speaker? When have you noticed your mistake? Did you act upon it? If yes how?

Comment: I edited my post, I hope it’s clearer now